# total of a product xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

am having dificulties on tackling this xslt of which gives me headache when it comes to summing up a total of receipt of which is stock * price.i need a guide of how i should put in the codes in an xslt sheet so as the results would be a table with the 2 offices and the total value of the 2 products of each customer.Am new in xml and xslt,.please help

```
<offices>
  <office>
    <customerproduct>
      <Price>10</Price>
       <Stock>20</Stock>
       <Ordered>25</Ordered>
    </customerproduct>
    <customerproduct>
      <Price>10</Price>
       <Stock>2</Stock>
       <Ordered>15</Ordered>
    </customerproduct>
   <receiptno.>1</receiptno.>
  </office>
  <office>
    <customerproduct>
      <Price>14</Price>
       <Stock>20</Stock>
       <Ordered>24</Ordered>
    </customerproduct>
    <customerproduct>
      <Price>100</Price>
       <Stock>2</Stock>
       <Ordered>100</Ordered>
    </customerproduct>
  <receiptno.>2</receiptno.>
 </office>
</offices>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to sum up? Please clarify.

Comment: @josh its the total amount of the of cost (stock * price).the  reciept of the 2 offices should include a total of the two customer products.

Comment: the question is:how do i sum up the totals of the customer products(stock * price) into separate receipt for the two offices.i need an xslt to guide me through am new in xslt,.

Comment: Hey body, you have a problem, please take a look at the XML syntax you mentioned. It is completely wrong. -1!

Comment: @ mohammad goudarzi--please help if you can,.have just fixed the problems and substantiated the issue,.ta

Comment: What is `Ordered` and how does it affect the wanted result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <html>
    <table border="1">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="office">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="concat('Office',position())"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(*/(Price*Stock))"/></td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided text after corrections of several malformities):

```
<offices>
    <office>
        <customerproduct>
            <Price>10</Price>
            <Stock>20</Stock>
            <Ordered>25</Ordered>
        </customerproduct>
        <customerproduct>
            <Price>10</Price>
            <Stock>2</Stock>
            <Ordered>15</Ordered>
        </customerproduct>
        <receiptno.>1</receiptno.>
    </office>
    <office>
        <customerproduct>
            <Price>14</Price>
            <Stock>20</Stock>
            <Ordered>24</Ordered>
        </customerproduct>
        <customerproduct>
            <Price>100</Price>
            <Stock>2</Stock>
            <Ordered>100</Ordered>
        </customerproduct>
        <receiptno.>2</receiptno.>
    </office>
</offices>
```

**produces (what we can *guess* is) the wanted result:**

```
<html>
   <table border="1">
      <tr>
         <td>Office1</td>
         <td>220</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Office2</td>
         <td>480</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</html>
```